# Should a Spliterator be reusable after an exception is thrown by the Consumer function?

Tags: java, java-8, spliterator

`Spliterator` takes an arbitrary `Consumer` function in its `tryAdvance` and `forEachRemaining` methods.

What should the state of the spliterator be if the consumer throws an exception? If the consumer passed to `forEachRemaining` throws an exception after 10 items (which is then propagated out & caught), should the next call to `tryAdvance` in the spliterator return the 11th item, or should the spliterator be considered dead & invalid at that point?

The javadocs are ambiguous on this point; they just say that any exceptions will be propagated out, with no reference to the spliterator's state past that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't go further after the fail.

The spliterator stops its work and no longer iterates over the elements. Even if there are remaining elements.

An exception in `forEachRemaining` for a specific element means that the computation for the whole group is over.

> Traversal and splitting exhaust elements; each Spliterator is useful for only a single bulk computation.

An example how `Spliterators.ArraySpliterator` handles this.

```
Spliterator<String> spliterator = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").spliterator();
System.out.println(spliterator.estimateSize());

try {
    spliterator.forEachRemaining(s -> {
        if (s.equals("b")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    });
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}

System.out.println(spliterator.estimateSize());
spliterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

---

```
3
a
0
```

AFAIK, most of `Spliterator`s based on a collection/array work in this way.

Comment: To be more specific, most `Spliterator`s with a dedicated `forEachRemaining` implementation read their state into local variables and then alter the instance state to be fully consumed, before using the local variables in the actual processing loop. That way, being fully consumed no matter what happens during the processing is implied, i.e. there is no need to handle exceptions specially. But keep in mind that `estimateSize()` is not required to reflect the changed state after traversal.